# the thebibliography style truck

Tags: bibliographies

I have used bibtem (see the screen shot please, using google scholar I paste bibtex (blue link) and it's done! here is the screen shot from gogle scholar  [image: an example]but with `thebibliography and \bibitem` is it different I wonder how to do it? 
here is my .bib file [my file .bib](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOY0lZdUJWb2RObzQ/view?usp=sharing)
let 's take this example

```
   \begin {document}
   \begin{thebibliography}{6}
    %
   \bibitem {25} T. Wang, S.-U. Guan, and F. Liu.: Ordered incremental 
    attribute learning based on mrmr and neural networks,” International 
    Journal of Design, Analysis and Tools for Integrated Circuits and 
    Systems, vol. 2,no. 2, pp. 86–90, (2011).

   \bibitem {9} R. Agrawal and R. Bala, “Incremental bayesian classification 
    for multivariate normal distribution data,” Pattern Recognition Letters, 
    vol. 29, no. 13, pp. 1873–1876, 2008.
    \end{thebibliography}

    bla bla \cite{9,25} bla bla 
    \end{document}
```

the first one start with "T" the other "A" this not right knowing that am doing it manually .. 
to the best of my knowledge that it has to be on this format:
 the problem is that I don't knwo from where and if I have to do It manually

```
       \bibitem[label]**{cle} Auteur, TITRE, editeur, annee**
```

like I have found here :

```
 Exemple :
    \begin{thebibliography}{2}
     \bibitem[label]{cle} Auteur, TITRE, editeur, annee
     \bibitem[LAM94]{lam1} L. LAMPORT, {\it \LaTeX : A Document
      preparation system, Addison-Wesley, 1994}
     \end{thebibliography}
     %%%% fin exemple %%%%
```

am I supposded to write it manaully add the author name , year ... or there is a way like in bibtex ( am using google scholar and I have just to paste the bibtex link result) how to do in this case and thank you for your help

Comment: Please make your code snippets compilable!

Comment: If you create the `thebibliography` environment by hand, *you* are in charge of every single design and formatting aspect. Perfectly flexible, but also utterly tedious.

Comment: @Mico thank you for your feedback I really don't know how to proceed I have to use `thebibliography` I don't know IF you have see my file.bib  I have about 20 references and IT will be more I have to use it but I would like to find how without doing it by my hund as in bibtex it is really very simple it is the first time I use the ` thebibliography` am really weired any suggestion !

Comment: Please explain why you  *have to* create the `thebibliography` environment by hand. Since you've assembled a perfectly good `.bib` file (called `myfile.bib`, right?), please explain why you don't select a suitable bibliography style --`abbrvnat` seems like a promising candidate -- via a `\bibliographystyle` directive, load the `natbib` package with the options `numbers` and `square`, provide the directive `\bibliography{myfile}` where you want the bibliography to appear, provide all needed `\cite` instructions, and then run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Thank you @Mico I am going to do as you said thank you :)